# How to define set from circle in Python script

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to define set to circles in a Python script for abaqus.

```
for j in range (45):
    x=data[2*j]    # Coordinate X of the center of the circle 
    y=data[2*j+1]  # Coordinate X of the center of the circle
                  # r = Radius circle
    print  (mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances
        ['matrix-1'].edges.findAt((x+r,y,0),)) 

    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Set(name='Set-%d'%(j+1), edges=
    mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances
        ['matrix-1'].edges.findAt((x+r,y,0),))
```

Now I can not I define set for circular

I am grateful for help

[Image of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeQPb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to feed `findAt` a "tuple of tuples" so that it returns a sequence:

```
edges=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances
    ['matrix-1'].edges.findAt(((x+r,y,0),),)
```

alternately get the index of the found edge and build your own sequence:

```
 assem=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
 instance=assem.instances['matrix-1']
 ind=instance.edges.findAt((x+r,y,0),).index
 assem.Set(name='Set-%d'%(j+1),edges=instance.edges[ind:ind+1])
```

I'm assuming your `print` worked. If you get an "edge not found" error that's a different matter.

Comment: work it, thanks for answer .

This mode is for Geometry mode. What should be done to define a category node? And select nodes around the circle?

Comment: after meshing the nodes will be available on the set you just made, `instance.sets['Set-xx'].nodes`

Comment: I do not understand how I use?
Please explain more

Comment: what do you want to do? There is no need to define a node set, one is created automatically when you define the edge set. more than that you should start a new question.  (dont forget to accept this one if you find it useful)

Comment: this code is for geometry mode , i need to define node for edge circle                         facemat=mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['matrix-1'].edges.findAt((x+r,y,0),)
m = facemat.index

mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.Set(name='Set-%d'%(j+1), edges=
 mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['matrix-1'].edges[m:m+1])